# In MySQL, how do I do a bulk update to a LIKE query, removing a character?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following MySQL query that pulls back 400 records:

```
SELECT email FROM user WHERE email LIKE 'GMSD%@law.com'
```

Returns:

**GMSDK001@law.com** through **GMSDK400@law.com**

What I want to do is remove the **K** from all 400 of these e-mail addresses in one easy `UPDATE`, so the return would be **GMSD001@law.com** through **GMSD400@law.com**.

How can I do this from a `LIKE` query? Using RegEx somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial query seems... off:

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE user LKE ...
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE email LIKE ...
```

Also, `LIKE 'GMSD%@law.com'` should probably be `LIKE 'GMSDK%@law.com'`, to capture values that actually have a `K` in it.

I would expect something simple, like using MySQL's `REPLACE()` function should handle this:

```
UPDATE
  users
SET
  email = REPLACE(email, 'GMSDK', 'GMSD')
WHERE
  email LIKE 'GMSDK%@law.com'
```

Edit: In my experience, table names are `plural`, so `users` instead of `user`. If you are indeed using `user`, adjust as required.

Comment: Correct, it's supposed to be `email` sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

As the where clause only finds mails with GMSD at the start and @law.com at the end, you should not have any side effects

```
CREATE tABLe user (email varchar(100))
```

```
INSERT INTO user VALUEs('GMSDK001@law.com'),('GMSDK400@law.com')
```

```
UPDATE user
SET email = REPLACE(email,'GMSDK','GMSD') WHERE email LIKE 'GMSD%@law.com'
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM user
```

| email |
| --- |
| GMSD001@law.com |
| GMSD400@law.com |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CRUpWADq)

if you have much more complicated emails, which doesn't seemed to be in your example data, you can also use regular expressions, which actually only replaces the first occurrence of the search pattern, which the replace would replace also

```
UPDATE user
SET email = REGEXP_REPLACE(email, '^GMSDK', 'GMSD') WHERE email LIKE 'GMSD%@law.com'
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM user
```

| email |
| --- |
| GMSD001@law.com |
| GMSD400@law.com |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uImRBAja)

Comment: "you should not have any side effects" Assuming GMSDK isn't repeated in any of the emails

Comment: If the examples were more complicated (e.g. GMSDKGMSDK@law.com), could use `REGEXP_REPLACE(email, '^GMSDK', 'GMSD')` to ensure only the first GMSDK is replaced, although that doesn't seem to be necessary here.

Comment: if GMSD is inthe text like AGMSD  the where clause wouldn't find any matches

Comment: @EdmCoff i think they are generated emails, so the pattern will not be much more complicated